# View on Map Button: hot to activate a control?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problems activating a control in google maps, my goal is when I click the control I want it to zoom in on a certain marker in the map and display the associated infowindow.

Here is my .html file

```
<div id="DetailsPanel">
    <div id="AdamsonDetails">
        <div id="ADUimages">
            <img src="img/doodle1.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/doodle2.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/doodle3.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div id="InfoTab">
            <div id="ViewOnMap" onclick="ViewADU()">VIEW ON MAP</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="SICDetails">
        <div id="SICImages">
            <img src="img/sic1.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/sic2.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/sic3.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HomeDetails">
        <div id="HomeImages">
            <img src="img/home1.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/home2.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/home3.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

This is the javascript that generates the markers

```
for (var i = 0; i < ManilaPlaces.length; i++) {
    var place = ManilaPlaces[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]),
        map: map,
        icon: PlaceMarker,
        title: place[0],
        zIndex: place[4]
    });
    // Add marker to array
    ManilaMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

This one generates the infowindow

```
function ADUInfo() {
    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><img src="lodging.png"> ADU</h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p>text here ' +
        'text here</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    ManilaInfoWindows[0] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var ADUmarker = ManilaMarkers[0];
    //Marker Zoom and Closing of other infowindow
    ADUmarker.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(ADUmarker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(17);
        map.setCenter(ADUmarker.getPosition());
        ManilaInfoWindows[0].open(map, ADUmarker);

    });
}
```

The function below is my code that doesn't work note that the ShowMap() executes a function which shows the map on the screen which it successfully does including the map.setZoom(17) but it doesn't execute the third row code

```
function ViewADU() {
    ShowMap();
    map.setZoom(17);
    map.setCenter(ADUmarker.getPosition());
}
```

Everything in the code works except for that one, been trying to figure it out but nothing works.

Comment: You can't access `ADUmarker` in `ViewADU` function because you declared it in `ADUInfo` function. Create a global variable.

Comment: Exactly sir I just figured it out

Comment: I just figured it out so I changed my code it wasn't accessing adumarker since it was inside a function just like what MrUpsidown said so I just used the global variable.

    function ViewADU() {
       ShowMap();
       map.setCenter(ManilaMarkers[0].getPosition());
       map.setZoom(17);
       ManilaInfoWindows[0].open(map,ManilaMarkers[0]);
    }

Wew kinda regret posting my question